# Get variable and associate stuff to it

Tags: jquery, variables

I have these variables:

```
var menuItem_place = 0;
var menuItem_position = 0;
var menuItem_limit = parseInt($('.slideshowImage').length) - 1;
```

They are the key variables of a slideshow I have. I need to associate css properties and some animated elements to the variable `menuItem_place`.

For example:

```
if(slideshowItem_place = 0){
  $(this).({'background-color':'black'}, 150);
}
```

I've tried a bunch of if/else but it doesn't work.
Full context - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p6Uxd/4/).

Comment: I don't understand what your question is - the jsfiddle seems to be working fine.

Comment: I need something extra - imagine I want to change the menuItem_3 color when it's inside the centerArea div, but I want to do it by fetching the menuItem_place variable.

Comment: You should add this to your question. Also, where in the jQuery script are you trying to add this behaviour?

Comment: Right after the variables - I don't want this kind of code to be associated with the buttons. Therefore the request to associate it directly to the variables. I'm sorry, I'm having a hard time expressing myself... I'm not a Javascript/jQuery savvy - not sure of the right terminology.

Comment: Hello Pedro! I honestly think that a big part of solving a problem is actually managing to put it in the right words; you can only solve a problem that you understand. That's probably why you are getting all those downvotes. That said, you want to associate different animations to different contents depending on whether they are inside the frame or outside?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to attach a callback to a variable. Callbacks are only for something that happens in an unpredictable way - generally, user input. With a variable, you can always track down those places where the code is using it.

What you're really looking for is the common place where those variables are changed - in effect, the place where menu items are animated. If you look at each of the callbacks for `click` events, you'll notice they each call `menu_animateClick();` at the end - this is likely where you'll want to make any changes.

The first line resets all of the menu items to the original size:

```
contents.animate({margin: 20, height: '64%', lineHeight: '63px'}, 300);
```

The second line enlarges the selected menu item:

```
$(contents.get(menuItem_place)).stop().animate({margin: 0, height: '100%', lineHeight: '99px'}, 100);
```

The third line figures out how many pixels the menu has to move:

```
menuItem_position = 0 - (menuItem_place * 200);
```

And the last line actually moves the menu over to the selected menu item:

```
$('#menuContainer').stop().animate({left: menuItem_position + 'px'}, 300);
```

In that function, it uses the snippet `$(contents.get(menuItem_place))` to get the content of the current menu item, and simply `contents` to retrieve the contents of *all* menu items. To set the selected menu item to black, you can try something like this:

```
$(contents.get(menuItem_place)).stop().css('background-color', 'black').show(100);
```

Although setting it back to its original color is something that you'll still have to figure out!